# Javascript form date check

Tags: javascript

```js
var myForm = document.getElementById("form");
document.bgColor="#FFFFCC";       //page styling
myForm.style.color="blue"; 
myForm.style.fontSize="20px";
myForm.style.fontWeight="400";
myForm.style.fontFamily="arial";


function validateForm() //form validation
{
 var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname"); //declared variables
 var lastname = document.getElementById("lastname");
 var postcode = document.getElementById("postcode");
 var email = document.getElementById("email");
 var cardtype = document.getElementById("cardtype");
 var cardnumber = document.getElementById("cardnumber");
 var ccv = document.getElementById("ccv"); 
 var month = document.getElementById("month");
 var year = document.getElementById("year");
      
 if (firstname.value==""){ //validate first name
  alert("Your first name can not be left blank");  
  firstname.focus();
  return false;
 }  
 if (lastname.value==""){ //validate last name 
  alert("Your last name can not be left blank");  
  lastname.focus();
  return false;
 } 
 if (postcode.value.length!=4){ //validate post code 
  alert("Your post code must be 4 numbers in length");  
  postcode.focus();
  return false;
 }
 if (isNaN(document.getElementById("postcode").value)){
  alert("Your postcode can not contain letters");  
  postcode.focus();
  return false;
 }
 if (email.value.length<5 || email.value.indexOf("@")== -1){ //validate email
  alert("Your email must not be less than 5 charcters in length, it must contain an @ and a .");  
  email.focus();
  return false;
 } 
 if (email.value.indexOf(".")== -1){ 
  alert("Your email must not be less than 5 charcters in length, it must contain an @ and a .");  
  email.focus();
  return false;
 } 
 if (cardtype.value == ""){
  alert("Please enter your card type");  
  email.focus();
  return false;
 }
 if (cardnumber.value.length!=16){ //validate card number length
  alert("Your card number must be 16 numbers in length");  
  cardnumber.focus();
  return false;
 } 
 if (isNaN(document.getElementById("cardnumber").value)){
  alert("Your card number can not contain letters");  
  cardnumber.focus();
  return false;
 }      
 if (ccv.value.length!=3){ //validate ccv number length
  alert("Your ccv must be 3 numbers in length");  
  ccv.focus();
  return false;
 }
 if (isNaN(document.getElementById("ccv").value)){
  alert("Your ccv must be a number");  
  ccv.focus();
  return false;
 }  
} 
function checkDate(){ //check expiry date of card
 var date = new Date();
 var month = date.getMonth()+1; //get current month
 var year = date.getYear()+1; //get current year
 var expiryMonth = document.getElementById("month").value;
 var expiryYear = document.getElementById("year").value;

 if (month == expiryMonth)//check if the current month has not expired
 {
  alert("Your card has expired");
  month.focus();
  return false;  
 }
 if (year == expiryYear) //check if the current year has not expired
 {
  alert("Your card has expired");
  year.focus();
  return false;
 }
 return false;//so the data is not cleared
 
}
 //alert("Your order has been successfully submitted thank you"); //notify user of correct submission
 //return true;
 
 //open up help window
function Popup(){ 
  window.open( "file:///C:/Users/Andy2411/Desktop/4JSB/assignment/html/help.html", "myWindow", 
  "status = 1, height = 500, width = 500, resizable = 0" );
  return;
 }
```

```css
form{width:700px;margin:0 auto;}
#Div1{float:;width:300;height:300;border:2px solid;border-radius:10px;padding:10px;padding-bottom:20px;background-color:;box-shadow:0 0 10px #2DADAC;position: relative;  top: -5%;   transform: translateY(5%);}

#Div2{float:;width:300;height:300;border:2px solid;border-radius:10px;padding:10px;background-color:;box-shadow:0 0 10px #2DADAC;position: relative;  top: -10%;   transform: translateY(10%);}

#Div3{text-align:center;margin:0 auto;display:;position: relative;  top: -190%;   transform: translateY(190%);}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!--Pseudocode
 INPUT firstname, lastname, postcode, email, cardtype, cardnumber, ccv, expiryMonth, expiryYear
 onsubmit = DO validateForm()
 END
 
 MODULE validateForm()
 IF (firstname =="") THEN
 OUTPUT error in firstname
 RETURN false
ENDIF
 IF (lastname =="") THEN
 OUTPUT error in lastname
 RETURN false
ENDIF
 IF (postcode.length!=4)   THEN
 OUTPUT error in postcode
 RETURN false
ENDIF
 IF (isNaN(document.getElementById("postcode").value)) THEN
 OUTPUT error in postcode
 RETURN false
ENDIF
 IF (email.value.length<5 || email.value.indexOf("@")== -1) THEN
 OUTPUT error in email
 RETURN false
ENDIF
 IF email.value.indexOf(".")== -1) THEN  
 OUTPUT error in email
 RETURN false  
ENDIF   
 IF (cardnumber.length!=16) THEN
 OUTPUT error in cardnumber
 RETURN false
ENDIF
 IF (isNaN(document.getElementById("cardnumber").value))
 OUTPUT error in cardnumber
 RETURN false
ENDIF
 IF (ccv.length !=3) THEN
 OUTPUT error in ccv
 RETURN false
ENDIF 
 IF (isNaN(document.getElementById("ccv").value))
 OUTPUT error in ccv
 RETURN false
ENDIF
 IF (month == expiryMonth) THEN
 OUTPUT error in month
 RETURN false
ENDIF
 IF (year == expiryYear) THEN
 OUTPUT error in year
 RETURN false
ENDIF
 OUTPUT correct
 RETURN true
END validateForm()-->

<head>
<title>Assignment4JSB</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css2/assignment.css" />
</head>
<body>
<form name=”userForm” autocomplete="on" id="form" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<script src="../js2/assignment.js"></script>
<div id="Div1">
<h3>Order Form</h3>
<fieldset>
<legend>Enter your Details here</legend></br>
First name: <input type="text" id="firstname" size="30" />
<br /><br />
Last name: <input type="text" id="lastname" size="30" />
<br /><br />
Postcode: <input type="text" id="postcode" size="4" />
<br /><br />
Email: <input type="text" id="email" size="30" />
<br/><br/>
</fieldset>

<!--<table> 
<tr>
<td><label for="FirstName">First Name</label></td> 
<td><input type="text" name="FirstName" id="firstname" size="30" required="required" autofocus /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="LastName">Last Name</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="LastName" id="lastname" size="30" required="required" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="PostCode">Postcode</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="PostCode" id="postcode" size="4" required="required" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="Email">Email</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Email" id="email" size="30"/></td>
</tr>
</table>-->

<h3>Payment Details</h3>
<fieldset>
<legend>Please enter your payment details</legend><br/>
Credit Card  <select id="cardtype">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Mastercard">Mastercard</option>
<option value="Visa">Visa</option>
<option value="AmericanExpress">American Express</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
Card number  <input type="text" id="cardnumber" size="18"/>
<br/></br>
CCV  <input type="text" id="ccv" size="3"/>
<br/></br>
Expiry MM/YY  <select id="month" onsubmit="checkDate()">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="month">01</option>
<option value="month">02</option>
<option value="month">03</option>
<option value="month">04</option>
<option value="month">05</option>
<option value="month">06</option>
<option value="month">07</option>
<option value="month">08</option>
<option value="month">09</option>
<option value="month">10</option>
<option value="month">11</option>
<option value="month">12</option>
</select>
<select id="year" onsubmit="checkDate()">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="year">2016</option>
<option value="year">2017</option>
<option value="year">2018</option>
<option value="year">2019</option>
<option value="year">2020</option>
<option value="year">2021</option>
<option value="year">2022</option>
<option value="year">2023</option>
<option value="year">2024</option>
<option value="year">2025</option>
<option value="year">2026</option>
</select>
</fieldset>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="Div3">
<button type="submit" >Submit</button>
<button type="button" onClick="Popup()">Help</button><br/>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a JavaScript assignment to write a basic form and validate user input, I have gotten to the stage where I have written a function to check expiry date of credit card (The month and year have to be checked against the current date) then a confirmation to the user of a successful submission.I also want to increase the size of the 'help' and 'submit' buttons and move them up vertically to the bottom of the form. I am having trouble getting this date check to work,  I will attach my work so far,any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need  to check the year first and then the month.

```
if (year > expiryYear) //check if the current  year has not expired
    {
        alert("Your card has expired");
        month.focus();
        return false;       
    }

if (year == expiryYear)
    {
        if(month >= expiryMonth) //check if the current month has not expired
        {
          alert("Your card has expired");
          month.focus();
          return false;
        }       
    }
```

Or you you can simply write it as

```
 if (year > expiryYear || ((year == expiryYear && month >= expiryMonth)) //check if the current  year has not expired
        {
            alert("Your card has expired");
            month.focus();
            return false;       
        }
```